# Magento 2 Check-out issue | An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, onepage-checkout

When trying to place a order I get "**`An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.`**"

In the console I get this:

```
POST https://www.mydomain.co.uk/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information 400 (Bad Request)
```

I use **Magento ver 2.1.8** and **World Pay** as payment gateway. It was working fine in "`Test`" mode and when switched World Pay to "`Live`" it gave me that error. Now even when I change back to "`Test`" it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily find the actual error by installing the Mage2 Module Experius ExceptionDebugger

> https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-ExceptionDebugger

But you can also check this manually more information how to debug the checkout manually I would like to referrer you to my codeblog

> https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-checkout-debuggen/

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: That very much helped! https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-checkout-debuggen/